# How do i make a python program allow itself through firewall?

Tags: python, windows, firewall

I am trying to create a simple chat application using sockets(UDP) and i would like to make it automatically allow itself through firewall, like every other application does. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Jesus, I hope python can't force itself through my firewall

Comment: _a simple chat application_: you have not exactly over-specified your application.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of a firewall is that *it* decides who gets through and who doesn't.  So in principle, this is not possible, and that's a good thing!

Most firewalls, however, are configured to allow e.g. web traffic (port 80) to pass.  So you have to find out what ports *your* firewall has open, and use these.

Comment: Yes i know , but the thing is that i have been trying to get such a program to work but it did not because the firewall would not let it even though the port was open(i tried multiple ones). After that i found out that python was not allowed through windows defender's firewall and i had to manually enable it and that is what i am trying to avoid. Also, thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: So your question is really: "how can I create firewall rule that allows just this one python program"?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much...(sorry for being inaccurate but i am new here and have almost no experience in networking and web security issues like firewall)

Comment: That's no problem at all.  Some times, asking a question makes you bump into the real issue.  Just pose a new question - people are willing to help here.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will pose a new question!